# Контакт лист Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Нужно реализовать контакт-лист. В самом элементе контакта содержится название и рядом с каждым контактом должны быть кнопки. Как можно реализовать этот механизм с кнопками?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю вам подойдёт [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=ru)

Comment: И плюс кастомный adapter